# How to push local changes to a new branch from master in Github?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I had a local branch say, X. It had some conflict. I resolved it and by mistake merged it. I then reverted those commits from main using `git reset --soft <commit-hash>`. I deleted the local branch. Now, I have those changes in my local master. I want to push these changes as a new branch. I tried creating a new branch and pushing it. It shows working tree clean. How do I push the local changes in my master as a new branch in remote?
I tried :
`git checkout -b <branch>`
`git push -u origin <branch>`
gives working tree clean.

Comment: @mkrieger1 No. I mentioned above that I tried this it gives working tree clean.

Comment: Why does that prevent you from pushing the branch?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It says the branch has nothing to commit.

Comment: You still can push it.

Comment: Yeah. Even if I do that what will be the changes it will show in PR? Nothing.

Comment: Possibly. But you've pushed the branch which was what you were asking. Maybe you meant to ask a different question.

Comment: Sorry. It did contain the changes. Thanks.